# drop duplicates with a condition and merge if required

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
word = [ "the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog", "quick", "brown", "fox"]
tag = ["a", "a", "", "b", "a", "a", "c", "", "d", "e", "", "a", ""]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(word, tag))
df.columns = ["word", "tag"]

    word    tag
0   the a
1   quick   a
2   brown   
3   fox b
4   jumps   a
5   over    a
6   the c
7   lazy    
8   dog d
9   quick   e
10  brown   
11  fox a
```

---

I tried to remove duplicates, but this is not what I am looking for.

> df.drop_duplicates(["word"])

```
    word    tag
0   the a
1   quick   a
2   brown   
3   fox b
4   jumps   a
5   over    a
7   lazy    
8   dog d
```

1. The tags of quick (a and e) should be merged like.. quick ae
2. bron and fox are duplicates. But in that case keep the words with tags and remove the words with NULL tag
3. lazy is not associated with any tag - but that is OK because that word is not duplicated.

---

Update:

This is close. But I need the tags like ae and not a list.

```
ndf=df.groupby("word")["tag"].apply(list)
ndf = ndf.reset_index()
ndf.columns = ["word", "tag"]
```

---

Update:

This is what I have tried. But not sure if it is the correct (pythonic) way!

```
def myfunc(word):
    return "".join(word)

ndf["mytag"] = ndf.tag.apply(myfunc)
```

Comment: Do you need `df.groupby("word")["tag"].apply("".join).reset_index()` ?

Comment: Close. But I need unique tags. So it should never be "quick aae"

Comment: So need `df.groupby("word")["tag"].apply(lambda x:"".join(set(x))).reset_index()` ?

Comment: Or `df = df.drop_duplicates(['word','tag']).groupby("word")["tag"].apply("".join).reset_index()`

Comment: That works with this sample data. But not with the actual file. strange!

Comment: One idea - not traling whitespaces? How working `df['tag'] = df['tag'].str.strip()`, similar for first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some comments you need remove duplicates in column `tag` by sets for unique letters and then use `join` in lambda function:

```
ndf = (df.groupby("word")["tag"]
         .apply(lambda x: "".join(set(z for y in x for z in y)))
         .reset_index()
      )
print (ndf)
    word tag
0  brown    
1    dog   d
2    fox  ba
3  jumps   a
4   lazy    
5   over   a
6  quick  ea
7    the  ca
```

If perfomance and ordering is important is possible use `dict` trick:

```
f = lambda x: "".join(dict.fromkeys(z for y in x for z in y).keys())
ndf = (df.groupby("word")["tag"]
         .apply(f)
         .reset_index()
      )
print (ndf)
    word tag
0  brown    
1    dog   d
2    fox  ba
3  jumps   a
4   lazy    
5   over   a
6  quick  ae
7    the  ac
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
df_final = (df.fillna('').groupby('word', as_index=False).agg(''.join).replace({'':np.nan, 'Yes': 'No'}))
```

Which returns

```
   word  tag
0  brown  NaN
1    dog    d
2    fox   ba
3  jumps    a
4   lazy  NaN
5   over    a
6  quick   ae
7    the   ac
```

**EDIT** 
Without `NaN` to replace empty spaces

```
df_final = (df.groupby('word', as_index=False).agg(''.join).replace({'Yes': 'No'}))
```

so that

```
  word tag
0  brown    
1    dog   d
2    fox  ba
3  jumps   a
4   lazy    
5   over   a
6  quick  ae
7    the  ac
```